# Coerced to javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java

When I try to set Calender instance got following error in WAS7 ,we are calling webservice .

This works fine in WAS6 ,only issue with WAS7 .

```
reqHeaderAreaType.setCreationDateTime(Calendar.getInstance())
```

---

```
error :TypeError: setCreationDateTime(): 1st arg can't be coerced to javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar .
```

---

I tried with this solution  as well, but no luck.

```
    gcal = GregorianCalendar()
    dataTypeFac = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
xmlGregCal = dataTypeFac.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gcal)#GregorianCalendar Instance
reqHeaderAreaType.setCreationDateTime(xmlGregCal)
```